# Issues with dependency on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dependencies

I am trying to install Audacity on Ubuntu 18.04 but get errors about dependency

```
rafal@asus:~$ sudo apt install audacity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 audacity : Depends: libavcodec58 (>= 10:4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libavformat58 (>= 10:4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libavutil56 (>= 10:4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libportsmf0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libsoundtouch1 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsuil-0-0 (>= 1:0.10.6) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libtwolame0 (>= 1:0.4.0) but 0.3.13-3 is to be installed
            Depends: libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg-10~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how can I solve it?
I was not able to find any good answer in internet

Comment: Where did your `audacity` come from?   It wasn't intended for 18.04 as the `libc6` being asked for is 19.04 release or higher (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6) so your sources have been polluted with non-bionic components, or you grabbed the wrong `audacity` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=audacity)  I would suggest `apt-cache policy audacity libc6` and adding answer to your question.

Comment: Looks like you have unwisely added wrong-version repositories, PPAs, or other sources that provide packages that are *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Uninstall those wrong-version packages and delete the wrong-version repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: thanks to all suggestins. indeed it was something related to repo/PPAs. after I removed them and left only standard ones it worked fine.